# How to make a public node server

Tags: node.js, server, public

Ok, I have searched for hours on this, nothing is working the way it should so I have to be doing something wrong. It works fine on localhost:port but I can't get it to work remotely.

Here is the app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index', {title: 'Welcome', message: 'Hello ExpressJS!'});
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running Express...');
```

Here is my port fowarding configuration:

```
Name: HTTP
Service Type: TCP
External Starting Port: 80
External Ending Port: 80
Use the same port range for Internal Port: [Checked]
Internal IP Address: 192.168.1.11 (This is the pc I want to use)
```

DNS Configuration

```
Name: Blank Type: A TTL: 300 Target: My Ip Address
Name: WWW Type: A TTL: 300 Target: My Ip Address
```

If I use the www.mydomain.com I get nothing, If I use my IP address still nothing.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your express service is running on port `3000`, not `80`. You'll need to forward incoming traffic on port `80` to `192.168.1.11:3000`

Comment: How do I do that, there is no option in the router settings. I tried running the app on port 80 but that just causes errors, or just simply doesn't work.

Comment: @JoshBeyer I'd start with unchecking `Use the same port range for Internal Port` - my guess is once unchecked it'll let you set the internal port mapping.

Comment: I tried that, I set it to internal port 3000, It didn't have option for starting, or ending, It was just a single numerical input box. Doesn't work tho.

Comment: @JoshBeyer so if you navigate directly to the internal IP (assuming your on the network) on that port, you don't see your site? FWIW this is getting beyond the scope of this site, there's a full site dedicated to networking issues - [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have nginx installed, you could easily reverse proxy that port to the domain you want to access from the outside world.